# Unable to use React cloneElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to clone an element but no matter how I pass it React just errors with:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `BuilderEditor`.
```

Here's my simplified code:

```
const HelloComponent = (props) => <div>hello world</div>

const components = {
  hello: HelloComponent
}

const BuilderEditor = () => {

  const Component = components.hello

  // This works
  return <Component/>

  // How do I make this work?
  const Clone = cloneElement(Component, {foo: "bar"})
  return <Clone/>
}

const App = () => {
  return <Div><BuilderEditor/></div>
}
```

Docs seem to indicate that `cloneElement` returns a component but it doesn't appear to be.

A simple `console.log` of `Component` is as expected:

```
HelloComponent(props) {
  return react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a.createElement("div", {
    __source: {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 187
    },
    __self: this
  }
```

Inspecting `Cione` yields:

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
type: undefined
key: undefined
ref: undefined
props: {foo: "bar"}
```

How do I use this?

Comment: can you show what is present in `components[component]` ??

Comment: If you have a component called `FooInput`, when using the clone element you don't have to pass to it the name of the component, but its type. So, you should not write `cloneElement('FooInput')`, but instead `cloneElement(FooInput)` -notice that we do not have the `' '`-

Comment: The message you're getting isn't from `cloneElement`, it's because your `Widget` component is actually a plain string when it should be a function `props => JSX`. What you're doing will work if `components.fooInput` is a React component, not a string.

Comment: @JoshWilson just edited my question with simpler code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a big difference between React *elements* and React *components*.

```js
const element = <div />; // a div element; this is what components return
const Component = (props) => <div {...props} />; // a component, a function of Props to Element
```

`React.cloneElement` only works for the former. To add a prop to an element, for example, you would do this:

```js
const element2 = React.cloneElement(element, { style: { color: "red" } });
```

What you are probably trying to do is add a prop to a *component*. To do that, you'll want to render it from another component like this:

```js
const Component2 = React.memo(
  props => <Component {...props} style={{ color: "red" }} />
);
```

Since `Widget` appears to be a *component*, you should skip `cloneElement` and do something similar to the second example.

Comment: Yes you are right - creating new components from old one will prob work better I think. I am trying to workaround the fact that my component contains some form code that caches data - so the same data is showing up every time I render the component and Id like it "reset".